# How get input from url html and use it on href variable

Tags: php, html

i have a page in HTML which get in input an "id" variable by URL:

registration.html?id=123456789

Now i want use this "id" variable into an href variable inside registration.html file to write the "id" input parameter of php file described on href

Can I get some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it will need to be a .PHP file for *any* PHP code to execute.

Despite that, you're going to want to output `$_GET['id']`